# Confusion related to a derivation in a paper

Tags: regression, kernel-trick

I was reading this  paper:

> Ristovski, K., Das, D., Ouzienko, V., Guo, Y., Obradovic, Z.
>   [Regression Learning with Multiple Noisy
>   Oracles](http://www.ist.temple.edu/~zoran/papers/ristovski_ECAI2010.pdf).

This paper is basically about regression. The idea is to learn a regression model using predictions made by several noisy predictors and learn the best regression model combining the predictions from the predictors.

I am actually confused a bit in the equations. In the paper in equation 24,
they have given the regression model as

$$\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x^{(i)},w) & = & w^{T}\phi(x^{(i)}) \\
               & = & a^{T}\phi\phi(x^{(i)}) \\
               & = & k(x^{(i)})^{T}(K+LI_N)^{-1}t.
\end{eqnarray}$$

I didn't get how the last line in the above derivation came up.

Also it has mentioned that for a new input $x$

$$y(x) = k(x)^{T}(K+LI_N)^{-1}t,$$
where $k(x)$ is the vector with elements $k_i(x) = k(x^{(i)},x)$.
The kernel function used in the Gaussian kernel is

$$k(x^{(i)},x^{(j)}) = e^{-\frac{(x^{(i)}-x^{(j)})}{2{\sigma}^2}}.$$

I didn't get it. I mean lets say I have a new input $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ where $m$ is the number of features in an input. How am I supposed to calculate
$k(x)^{T}$? I didn't get this $k$ thing.

Can anyone please explain? I will be really grateful.